# Mysql Округление decimal

Tags: mysql

Поясните в чем проблема, тип данных поля decimal (10.6)

Запрос возвращает следующие значения, но вот в бд заносится с округлением

SET @turnover_usd_rate:=0.00011;

```
# Recalculate turnover USD
SET @turnover_usd:=0;
INSERT INTO `FB_revenue_report` (`date`, `product_id`, `turnover_usd`) 
SELECT NOW(), `product_id`, @turnover_usd:=(`turnover` * @turnover_usd_rate) AS `turnover_usd`
FROM `FB_revenue_report` WHERE `date` = DATE(NOW())
GROUP BY `product_id`
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `turnover_usd` = @turnover_usd

2019-06-19 08:42:10 22401220000024759   12.617
2019-06-19 08:42:10 22401220000026139   0.055
2019-06-19 08:42:10 22401220000026620   228.492
2019-06-19 08:42:10 22401220000026622   5.071
2019-06-19 08:42:10 22401220000026623   0.231
```

БД

```
228.000
5.000
0.000
13.000
0.000
```

Comment: Кто куда кого заносит? Если в таблицу FB_revenue_report, значит покажите её схему

Answer (score 0):

Решил проблему добавив кастинг к переменной при инсерте дублирующей записи

Было `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`turnover_usd`= @turnover_usd`

Изменил на `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`turnover_usd`= CAST(@turnover_usd AS DECIMAL(10, 3))`